# Area Problem. Finding the area between curves using calculus

Tags: calculus

Find the area between the curves in the first quadrant bound by the parabolas

$y^2 -x=1$, 
$y^2 -x=0$, 
$y^2 +x=5$,
$y^2 +x=4$

Comment: Did you try to [sketch](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%7By%5E2+-x%3D1,+y%5E2+-x%3D0,+y%5E2+%2Bx%3D5,+y%5E2+%2Bx%3D4%7D+for+0%3Cx%3C5,+0%3Cy%3C3) the parabolas to get a good idea of the region?

Comment: No I had the computer do it for me.

Comment: Whether you did it manually or used a computer for it; does it help to set up the integral(s)...? If not, where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Heterotrophy and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

Due to symmetry it is equivalent to the area between the inverse functions:
$$y_1=x^2-1, y_2=x^2, y_3=-x^2+5, y_4=-x^2+4.$$
The $x$-coordinates of the intersection points are:
$$y_2=y_4 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{2};$$
$$y_2=y_3 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{\frac52};$$
$$y_1=y_4 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{\frac52};$$
$$y_1=y_3 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{3}.$$
The definite integral:
$$A=2\left(\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{\frac52}} x^2-(-x^2+4)dx+\int_{\sqrt{\frac52}}^{\sqrt{3}} (-x^2+5)-(x^2-1)dx\right).$$
Can you finish it?